# Finding a Topology from a Subbase

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

The book I am using for my Introduction of Topology course is Principles of Topology by Fred H. Croom.

> > Let $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. $\mathcal{T}_X$ has a subbase $\mathcal{S}=\{\{1\}, \{1,2,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4,5\},\{4\}\}$. $A=\{1,3,5\}$, $B=\{1,5\}$, $\mathcal{T}_A$ = subspace topology. Compute $\overline{B}, B^{'}, \text{int}B$ in $\mathcal{T}_X$ and $\mathcal{T}_A$.

The one thing that confuses me the most is trying to derive the topology $\mathcal{T}_X$. My idea was to derive a base from the subbase, and then use the base to span the topology $\mathcal{T}_X$. Am I on the right track?

I have a base, not sure if it is correct though: $B=\{ \emptyset,\{1\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{2,3\}\}$. Any suggestions?

---

Thank you for taking the time to read this question. I greatly appreciate any assistance you may provide.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have forgotten the 1-fold intersections: The sets of $\cal S$ itself.

With this base, the number $5$ would not be covered, and $\{3,4,5\}$ would not be open.

The base is $\mathcal B=\{ \emptyset, \{1\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{2,3\}, \{3,4,5\} \}$. With this you can compute the interior of $B=\{1,5\}$. Just find all points $x\in B$ such that one of these base sets contains $x$ and is a subset of $B$. Also note that $B$ is closed, and that each point of $B$ is isolated.

Comment: I have the following thus far in $\mathcal{T}_X$: int$B=\{1\}$, ext$B=\{2,3,4\}$, cl$B=\{1,5\}$. I am trying to find the set of limit points of $B$, also known as the derived set, in $\mathcal{T}_X$. Thank You once again for your help.

Comment: @Kevin_H: $B$ has no limit points, all its points are isolated.